# Report, ordering by summarized field

Tags: reporting

I'm new at SF, from an SQL background.

I want a report of sales by zipcode, for our top n zipcodes by sales.
On each opportunity, we have an amount field, and a shipped-to-zip field.
In a summary report I can summarize amount, grouping by zip.
In a tabular report, I can sort by either column by clicking on it.
In summary report, I can hide details.
However, I can not find a way to group sum(amount) by zip, and order zip codes descending by sum(amount).

This seems like it would be such a common request, I suspect I am overlooking something very basic.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, this has not been possible. The good news is that this ability is being released in the Spring '14 Salesforce release coming to your instance this week or next.

For more information about this feature, see the section on Flexible Sorting in Reports from the release notes:

https://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_spring14_release_notes.pdf